# Minimal time problem to stop a rocket

Tags: calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, optimal-control

> Blockquote
> A rocket moves with uniform rectilinear motion with speed $v(0) = V_0$, without friction. The pilot can brake by decelerating.
> We call $A$ the maximum deceleration that the motor can achieve.
> The tank contains a limited amount of gasoline equal to $K$.
> We assume that there is a quadratic (or more generally a superlinear) relationship between the fuel consumed and the acceleration e.g.
> $$ k (t) dt = a (t) ^ 2 dt $$
> where $k(t)$ is the amount of gasoline consumed at time t.
> Find $a(t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq T$ (in the space of bounded functions) which minimizes the time $T$ to stop the rocket, such that the speed at time $T$ is $v(T) = 0$.
> Blockquote

Do you know some references/notes/books that contain the solution to this problem? Or do you know the solution?

Comment: This problem seems to be not well posed. Without restrictions on $k(t)$ as $k(t)\to\infty$ we have $T\to 0$. Any way, I recommend Applied Optimal Control- Bryson and Ho

Comment: Thanks, @Cesareo. You are right. Actually, I was thinking about this problem in discrete time, where the acceleration is bounded because the gasoline is bounded too. Passing to the continuous-time formulation I forgot to say that a(t) must be bounded. I will have a look at the reference you suggested. Thanks.